# How to upgrade azure sdk to 2.4?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-worker-roles

My existing project, uses Azure .NET SDK 2.1. I wanted to upgrade the SDK to 2.4, so i dowloaded the latest from [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/) for VS 2012. After successfull installation, when i opened up my solution, the cloud projects did not load. Thats ok, as they have been created using a lower version. So i removed them and created newer cloud projects.

But the thing which astonishes me is, there are many places in the worker role project where its throwing build error as it is not able to find out the assemblies and methods. Is there any easier way to upgrade to sdk 2.4 without making code changes. Which i think is a bad idea to make changes to the stable code, just for SDK upgrade.

Comment: Perhaps some examples of what lines of code are throwing build errors would help.  The Azure service runtime is the same, but if you upgraded from an old storage client library (1.7 for example) to a newer one then there are breaking changes.  You can downgrade your SCL reference to the older version if the code change are too much to make at this time.

Answer (score 1):

When you open a project created using 2.1 SDK and try to open it using 2.4 SDK, you should see the project upgrade dialog which gives you the option to either download 2.1 SDK or convert existing project to target 2.4. Selecting the convert option should upgrade the project to 2.4. Any errors in this process will be reported in the project migration summary report.

If you are not seeing this dialog, then you might still have 2.1 sdk on your machine in addition to 2.4 sdk. In that case, you can go the Azure project properties. That will give you the option to upgrade your project to 2.4.

In regard to the build errors that you are getting for new projects, the error details will help in identifying the root cause.